# I try to deploy a contract on rinkeby testnet with some eth but there is an error occurred

Tags: blockchain, solidity, remix

The error I face in remix is Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted even if I have enough money to create a contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
// Get the latest ETH/USD price from chainlink price feed
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe {
    // safe math library check uint256 for integer overflows
    
    //mapping to store which address depositeded how much ETH
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    // array of addresses who deposited
    address[] public funders;
    //address of the owner (who deployed the contract)
    address public owner;
    
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }  
    function fund() public payable {
        // 18 digit number to be compared with donated amount 
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;
        //is the donated amount less than 50USD?
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
        //if not, add to mapping and funders array
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }
    function getPrice() public view returns(uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
         // ETH/USD rate in 18 digit 
         return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }

    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
        // the actual ETH/USD conversation rate, after adjusting the extra 0s.
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)try downgrading your compiler version to 0.5

if that does not work try this

2)In remix try to increase your gas limit to probably `8000000`

[image: Gas limit]

Answer (score 0):

You need a receve/fallback function to send ETH to a contract. Try to add these to your contract code:

> ```
>     receive() external payable {
>         // React to receiving ether
>     }
> ```